# Repeating Outlook calendar appointment on Android 2.3 calendar

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calendar, outlook, active-sync

I synchronize my Outlook 2010 calendar via an Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync account with my Samsung Galaxy SII (Android 2.3.5).

It works pretty good, except for appointments with repetition. I created a monthly appointment in Outlook with invited participants and then I see it as several sequential appointments per month on the Android calendar (e.g., I set last working day of each month in Outlook and instead of 8/31 only, it results in 5 appointments from 8/27 to 8/31 on the Android. After having had that for the first time, I deleted the appointment and created a new one, but with the same result.

Has anyone experienced a similar behaviour and knows how to work around that problem?